# Aurelia: data disappears in table when using DataTables jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, aurelia

I use the jQuery data tables plugin (https://datatables.net/).

You can use it on a html table like this:

```
$("#table").DataTable();
```

If I have a normal html table in my View and call the above in the `attached()` method of my view model all works fine.

But things go wrong when I try to do this when generating the table from data I get from my API.

The table gets generated but under it instead of saying something like "showing 0 to 10 of 93 entries" it says "showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries". Also, if I try to sort the table by a given column all the data disappears leaving just the column headers.

UPDATE:
I do not use any Ajax calls for sorting the table. I create my table from the data I get from my server. To elaborate: I get a json object from server. Use the json object to construct the table using "repeat.for='row of tableData' ". Calling the .DataTable() in attached hook creates the issue. I have tried creating a simple button that calls the .DataTable() method when clicked. It constructs the table properly. Seems like an issue with calling it in the attached() hook

Comment: I don't see much sense using datatables when you have aurelia binding. I'd rather use `repeat.for` to generate the rows. You can build any feature of Datables using Aurelia. That's just my opinion

Comment: I use repeat.for to generate my table. Datables is there for live-search, table pagination. I can build it, sure, but the question here is why is it not working as it should

Comment: This is likely a timing issue, aurelia uses async bindings, try it with a setTimeout in your attached method (use a couple of seconds delay). If it works, it's because you are waiting on async bindings to evaluate. The most common way to get around this is to queue your task on the task queue so it gets executed after any bindings waiting in the pipeline

Answer (score 3):

I agree with MJ, but you may be falling foul of timing issues.

Aurelia uses an async binding system which queues DOM updates to the micro task queue in order to batch them for performance reasons (that's why it's so quick)

You could try the following which should in theory allow any repeat bindings to be processed before your data tables are initialised.

```
import {TaskQueue} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(Element, TaskQueue)
export class DataTables {  
  constructor(element, taskQueue) {
    this.element = element;
    this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
  }

  attached() {
    this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(() => {
      // Init data tables here
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Issue persists. My problem is not that the data isn't displayed in the table. It is. But, for example, there is a message with "no data available in table" below but the data is there. But the second I try to sort a column or search all the data vanishes. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm sure I've had this working fine, here's a thought, do you have any custom element tags that you have self closed? All non standard HTML tags must have an explicit closing tag and cannot be self closing, this can cause weird behaviour

Comment: Also check that you have correctly created thead and tbody as I believe data tables is picky about what the DOM looks like before it creates the table

Comment: Checked. I dont use any custom elements. Just removed the repeat.for code and replaced it with an ordinary table. Table is generated properly. I guess its like you'd said, there is a timing issue.

Comment: Did you try with a long setTimeout?

Comment: No. Sorry, not sure what u meant by that. Like specify an argument in the attached method?

Comment: No use the built in js `setTimeout` method, it fires a callback function after a delay that you can specify, Google it and try that (put a couple of secs delay on)

Comment: It works with 100miliseconds and higher. I could if bind the table and display it when the setTimeout completes, or within it. 0.1 second is not a long wait but this is obviously a very dirty solution

Comment: Yes, it is a dirty solution, are you perchance using any `if` bindings in your view?

Comment: No. I only have repeat.for plus string interpolation. I read on tasqueue. Still didn't help

Comment: I'd say jump into the Gitter chatroom, someone can probably take a look there http://gitter.im/aurelia/discuss

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create a [custom element](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/templating/1.0.0-beta.1.2.7/doc/article/templating-custom-elements) for your DataTable object. You're most likely going to want to use a [custom binding](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/templating/1.0.0-beta.1.2.7/doc/article/templating-custom-attributes) on your DataTable element where you pass in the data. Lastly, you're going to want to call some kind of refresh or teardown/buildup function on your DataTable plugin in the "valueChanged" callback of the `rows` binding.

**dataTable.js**

```
@inject(Element)
export class DataTableCustomElement { 

    element;
    @bindable rows;

    constructor(Element) {
        this.element = $(Element);
    }

    rowsChanged(newValue, oldValue) {
        this.element.DataTable.refresh(); // or whatever it is
    } 
}
```

**view.html**

```
<data-table rows.bind="data.rows"></data-table>
```

I dunno anything about your DataTable API. It may not have been designed to deal with new data coming from the server. I'll leave that to the reader.

Comment: I do not use any Ajax calls for sorting the table. I create my table from the data I get from my server. To elaborate: