# Aurelia page life-cycle

Tags: aurelia

I had a problem with Aurelia's binding system. I want so.e clarification on how view and viewmodels interact.

Lets say I have a div. This div has child divs that get generated by Aurelia's "repeat.for". I then have a function that does something to the parent div and its children. Where or when do I call this function. From experience, I cant call the function in the attached() hook because  Aurelia's binding system is asynchronous so not all child divs may be ready by the time I call my function

Comment: What is this "something" you speak of?  I'm not too familiar with Aurelia, but in Knockout land, having knockout control the DOM and you control the DOM as well just leads to mess.  It's better to just build everything as bindings/plugins for knockout and have it all controlled together, I would assume it's similar for Aurelia.

Comment: Pretty much. Its the obvious way to go but what if u want to use a jQuery plugin. The asynchronous binding breaks compatability with some jquery plugins because they need the view to be ready

Comment: Generally I'd build a knockout binding that wraps the plugin functionality.

Comment: Can you explain how that will work please

Comment: I could in knockout land, but not for Aurelia.  It might help if you clarify your question with exactly what you're attempting to do, if you are using a jquery plugin, saying which one etc - if possible you would ideally create a [mcve] demonstrating the issue.

Comment: I actually had a problem like this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37530452/aurelia-data-disappears-in-table-when-using-datatables-jquery-plugin